# Subscribers that subscribed in the last 30 days but haven't purchased

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm using this logic in the Query Studio:

```sql
SELECT UUID 
FROM [CL_ACTIVE_SUBSCRIBERS]
WHERE S.UUID NOT IN (
  SELECT [Contact key] 
  FROM [CL-OrderCompleted]
) 
AND FORMAT(S.FIRST_TIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd') < DATEADD(D,-30,GETDATE())
```

`CL_ACTIVE_SUBSCRIBERS` and 'cl-ordercompleted' being a data extensions

there is any other way to do it with Data Views?

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can use [_Subscribers Data View](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-config-system-data-views#_subscribers) to pull information about subscription date.

As for purchase, it depends whether you have implemented [Collect.js to track conversion](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-config-behavioral-triggers#track-purchase). If yes then you can leverage Einstein Data Extension.

```
SELECT
    sub.SubscriberKey,
    sub.EmailAddress
FROM _Subscribers sub
LEFT JOIN Igo_Purchases igo ON igo.Subscriber_ID = sub.SubscriberID
WHERE igo.Subscriber_ID IS NULL
    AND CONVERT(DATE, sub.DateJoined) >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```